# Resetting admin password of Metabase in Docker Desktop Windows 11

Tags: docker-desktop, windows-11, metabase

Good day.

How do I reset the admin password of Metabase that is installed using Docker Desktop on Windows 11?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the answer can be found [here](https://www.metabase.com/docs/latest/people-and-groups/managing#resetting-the-admin-password). The guide says,

> If you’re a Metabase admin and have access to the server console, you
> can get Metabase to send you a password reset token:
>
> Stop the running Metabase application. Restart Metabase with
> reset-password email@example.com, where “email@example.com” is the
> email associated with the admin account: `java -jar metabase.jar reset-password email@example.com`

**MODIFYING THE FILE**

On Docker Desktop, what you need to do is to modify `run_metabase.sh` and add the `reset-password` flag as described above.

1. On Docker Desktop, this is easy. In Containers, look for Metabase. Under action, click on the 3-dotted button, and select View Files. Under `app` folder, select `run_metabase.sh` to open the file.
2. Add the `reset-password` flag with the admin email as described above. In my case, I modified line 172. Save the file.

[image]

At this point, you can now restart and continue following the guide above. **However, if you were like me, you will encounter a permission denied error and Metabase won't start successfully as before.** Modifying and saving the file in the Docker Desktop editor removed the execute flag of the file.

**FIXING THE Permission Denied Error**

To reset the file's permission, open a terminal in the WSL guest you are using.

1. Navigate to `/mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/version-pack-data`.
2. Perform a search of the `run_metabase.sh` file using `find . -name run_metabase.sh`. This will give you the location of the file.
3. Using that location, modify the permission of the file using `chmod +x path/to/run_metabase.sh`.
4. On Docker Desktop, try to run the Metabase again. It should work now. Copy the reset-password token provided in the terminal logs.

At this point, you need to revert the changes you've made in the `run_metabase.sh` file, reset the permission as described above, then restart Metabase again. You can now access the reset-password link and use the token obtained previously to reset the password of your Metabase admin account.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your docker run, add the command `"reset-password user@example.com"` where you use the admin account email. The logs will then provide a token which you can use to reset the password.

The docker container will exit after providing the token so you will have to restart the container (without the reset password command).

Reset the password by going to `http://<ip>:<port>/auth/reset_password/<token>`.

**Explanation:**

The docker entrypoint is `ENTRYPOINT ["/app/run_metabase.sh"]` which handles launching the application. The last part of that file states

```
# Launch the application
    # exec is here twice on purpose to  ensure that metabase runs as PID 1 (the init process)
    # and thus receives signals sent to the container. This allows it to shutdown cleanly on exit
    exec su metabase -s /bin/sh -c "exec java $JAVA_OPTS -jar /app/metabase.jar $@"
```

This `$@` means it will append any additional arguments that you provided to it. So there is no need to edit any files or go into a running docker container to stop and start something with a specific command. You can simply add the required command (as per https://www.metabase.com/docs/latest/people-and-groups/managing#resetting-the-admin-password) to the docker run command (or docker compose if you are using that).